# TYPO3 preview image of inline records

Tags: typo3

A tt_content custom content element (imageslider) has IRRE slides.

The slide record has a title and an image (filereference).

Is it possible to preview the image of the IRRE record?

The `previewRenderer` class seems to be oriented only on the page view.

`typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Form/Container/InlineRecordContainer.php` shows a TCA setting for headerThumbnail

However this TCA doesn't produce the headerThumbnail.

```
'appearance' => [
    'headerThumbnail' => [
        'field' => 'image',
        'width' => '45',
        'height' => '45c',
    ],
```

So a userFunc or something is needed to retrieve the fileUid for `field`? Or is there an easier solution possible?

[EDIT] An IRRE record could of course have multiple images. So I guess this should be a feature for the InlineRecordContainer class, like the previewRenderer class to adjust the look and content.

Answer (score 0):

Nice hint, that there should be custom thumbnails possible...

After diving a bit deeper in `InlineRecordContainer`, it seems to be clear, that this can't work (anymore?). There are (in v10/v11) the following lines:

```
// Renders a thumbnail for the header
if ($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['thumbnails'] && !empty($inlineConfig['appearance']['headerThumbnail']['field'])) {
    $fieldValue = $rec[$inlineConfig['appearance']['headerThumbnail']['field']];
    $fileUid = $fieldValue[0]['uid'];
```

For the UID of the thumbnail, the first array entry in the given field is used. But when debugging `$rec` (=`$data['databaseRow']`), we see, it is just the raw record, which means a FAL-field will not be an array but only an integer that counts the relations...

IMO this is a bug. I have just reported it: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/96188

Comment: Obviously it works in some cases, for example at the assets in a textmedia element. So I think rather a feature is missing, like get the fileUid from the sys_file_reference. Another TCA setting at the headerThumbnail section might be needed. `field` refers now indeed to a direct fileUid.